# Java how to fix "object is not an instance of declaring class" error?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to build a `User` class from SQL query `ResultSet`.

I am using my user class to get field names and use them as column names while building my `SELECT` query.

In this case my query has `id` and `email` in it's selections.

Query: `"SELECT " + String.join(", ", columns) + " FROM " + table + ";"`

```
public class User {

    private int id;
    private String email;

    public long getId() {

        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {

        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {

        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {

        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

I have the problem in my parser class where I parse the results from database to an `ArrayList<User>`. Meanwhile I need to get the column types and field types dynamically.

Here is the loop of rows retrieved from the database:

```
while (resultSet.next()) {

    // columnCount is equal to the classes field count
    // since ResultSet starts indexes from 1, I added 1 to columnCount
    for (int i = 1; i < columnsCount + 1; i++) {
        // get the class of the wanted results
        // Ex: User
        Class<? extends Object> object = instance.getClass();

        // column name from index
        // Ex: id
        String columnName = metaData.getColumnName(i);
        // setter method name in the class
        // Ex: setId
        String setterName = "set" + Utils.firstLetterToUpperCase(columnName);

        Method method = null;

        Class<?> type = null;
        try {
            // array of declared fields of the class
            // Ex: [id, email]
            Field[] fields = object.getDeclaredFields();

            // type of that field
            // since ResultSet starts indexes from 1, I subtracted 1 from `i`
            // Ex: int
            type = fields[i - 1].getType();

            // Ex:
            //      Method is equal to the `setId(int id)`
            //      setterName = setId, type = int
            method = object.getDeclaredMethod(setterName, type);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // getter method to invoke on resultSet object to get the type dynamically
        // Ex: getterName = getId
        String getterName = "get" + Utils.firstLetterToUpperCase(type.getName());

        try {
            Method resultSetGetterMethod = null;

            try {
                // Ex:
                //          public int com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(int) throws java.sql.SQLException
                //          easier: getInt(int x)
                //          getterName = getInt, type = int
                resultSetGetterMethod = resultSet.getClass().getMethod(getterName, type);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // this part gives the error
            // "object is not an instance of declaring class"
            // --------------------------------------------------------- //
            // Exception: "object is not an instance of declaring class" //
            // --------------------------------------------------------- //
            method.invoke(object,

                    // it should call `getInt(int x)` method 
                    // on `resultSet` with `i` as the argument, which
                    // is the index of the int column in the `resultSet`
                    resultSetGetterMethod.invoke(resultSet, i) // This line
            );
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        results.add(object);
    }
}
```

I tried to explain what I tried to do in the comments, if it's not clear enough I can update the question.

I marked the code that throws the excetion with:

```
// --------------------------------------------------------- //
// Exception: "object is not an instance of declaring class" //
// --------------------------------------------------------- //
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Can you tell us on which actual line the exception is taking place?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Updated Thanks!

Comment: what is `instance`? Where do you create it?

Comment: @MiserableVariable In this case it is equal to a `User` instance.

Comment: You realize you need to create a new instance of it for every iteration of `while (resultSet.next()) `.  Otherwise, Abdelhak's answer is on the right track.

Comment: Oh and the getter seems wrong too. `ResultSet` does not have a method named `getId`; it only has a `getString("id")`.

Comment: `resultSetGetterMethod` is `getInt(int x)` not `getId`

Comment: Why not use `getObject` instead, it removes the need for a lot of reflection code.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Because I didn't know that there is a method `getObject`. :D I will try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You invok the method with the class, but you need an instance of it, try this:

```
  method.invoke(instance,resultSetGetterMethod.invoke(instance,resultSet, i));
```

Comment: Try using null or without and give the feedback

Comment: @OzanKurt I am curious, do you not need to create new instances? Also, what about the `resultSetGetterMethod`? It cannot work as you have written.